# Expand default (dita) attributes

Tags: python, libxml2, dita

My python libxml2 differently processes the files with the default attributes, depending on what I want to know what. The example, using the DITA DTD (the package can be downloaded on www.dita-ot.org):

```
import libxml2
import libxsltmod

s = """<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XDITA Map//EN"
"file://.../dita-ot-2.2.1/plugins/org.oasis-open.dita.v1
_2/dtd/technicalContent/dtd/map.dtd">

<map title="Empty map">
</map>"""

libxml2.substituteEntitiesDefault(1)
xmldoc = libxml2.parseDoc(s)
print xmldoc
```

The output is as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XDITA Map//EN"
"file://.../dita-ot-2.2.1/plugins/org.oasis-open.dita.v1
_2/dtd/technicalContent/dtd/map.dtd">
<map xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
  title="Empty map" ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.2" domains="(topic delay-d)
  (map mapgroup-d)                           (topic indexing-d)
  (map glossref-d)                          (topic hi-d)
  (topic ut-d)                           (topic hazard-d)
  (topic abbrev-d)                          (topic pr-d)
  (topic sw-d)                          (topic ui-d)
  " class="- map/map ">
</map>
```

But if I comment-out `import libxsltmod`, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XDITA Map//EN"
"file://.../dita-ot-2.2.1/plugins/org.oasis-open.dita.v
1_2/dtd/technicalContent/dtd/map.dtd">
<map title="Empty map">
</map>
```

So, libxsltmod makes something to activate default attributes expansion. Would you please suggest what, and how I can activate this functionality through python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how *libxsltmod* enables this setting globally, but normally, DTD default attributes are added with the [parser option](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParserOption) `XML_PARSE_DTDATTR`. Use `readDoc` instead of `parseDoc` to provide parser options:

```
xmldoc = libxml2.readDoc(s, None, None, libxml2.XML_PARSE_DTDATTR)
```

Or, if you also want to substitute entities:

```
flags = libxml2.XML_PARSE_NOENT | libxml2.XML_PARSE_DTDATTR
xmldoc = libxml2.readDoc(s, None, None, flags)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to the `readDoc` function. However, please correct your answer, the flags should be `libxml2.XML_PARSE_NOENT | libxml2.XML_PARSE_DTDATTR`

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted the answer from @nwellnhof, but would like also to publish my investigations.

The initialization function `initlibxsltmod` of `libxslt` module sets the global variable:

```
xmlLoadExtDtdDefaultValue = XML_DETECT_IDS | XML_COMPLETE_ATTRS;
```

I have not found any possibility to access this variable from the `libxml2` Python/C binding code, but I have found that this variable is used to initialize a default 'parser context', and it is possible to create and use the parser context manually:

```
ctxt = libxml2.createDocParserCtxt(s)
opts = libxml2.XML_PARSE_NOENT | libxml2.XML_PARSE_DTDATTR
ctxt.ctxtUseOptions(opts)
ctxt.parseDocument()
xmldoc = ctxt.doc()
del ctxt
```

The Python/C function `readDoc` performs exacly this way (create context, set options, parse). The manual context createion is verbose, but probably is necessary in some situation.